# Gitlab CI Angular Artifacts not accessible

Tags: angular, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to build and deploy my angular project with gitlab pipelines. There are two jobs. One for building the angular app and one for the deployment. My `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this.

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
  - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install > /dev/null

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
    stage: build
    artifacts: 
        paths:
            - dist/
        expire_in: 1 week
    script:
        - npm run build --prod

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment: production
  image: mjsarfatti/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php-aws:latest
  before_script:
    - mkdir ~/.aws/
    - touch ~/.aws/credentials
    - printf "[eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = %s\naws_secret_access_key = %s\n" "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> ~/.aws/credentials
  script:
    - git checkout master
    - eb deploy my_project
  only:
    - master
```

The aws cli used in the deploy job builds the dockerfile located in my project root. My  problem is that 
every time when I run the deploy job I get this error:

```
Step 3/7 : COPY dist/src /usr/share/nginx/html
44 COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder648218383/dist/src: no such file or directory.
```

It seems like that the artifact from the previous build job is missing. What is wrong with my `gitlab-ci.yaml` file?

Comment: How about adding the `dist` folder to the `cache` paths as you did it with the `node_modules`? I'm not sure if it works, but it is worth to give it a try.

Comment: I think this is not the right solution as described here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-vs-artifacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When artifacts are extracted into other pipeline steps, it's extracted in a different location that your code that's pulled down via git. For me, I've seen the artifact(s) put in the parent directory from where my code is. So for example if I have this directory structure:

```
--- gitlab_ci_root
   --- my_code
```

The extracted artifacts will be put under `gitlab_ci_root`, not `my_code`.

You can test this by putting a couple of `ls`'s into your `deploy` step.

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment: production
  image: mjsarfatti/gitlab-ci-pipeline-php-aws:latest
  before_script:
    - ls # directory list of current directory, likely your code
    - ls ../ # directory list of the parent directory.
    - mkdir ~/.aws/
    - touch ~/.aws/credentials
    - printf "[eb-cli]\naws_access_key_id = %s\naws_secret_access_key = %s\n" "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> ~/.aws/credentials
  script:
    - git checkout master
    - eb deploy my_project
  only:
    - master
```

Once you find where the `dist/` directory is being extracted, then in your script you can mv the dist to wherever you need it to be.